# ClassNotFoundException from jar in Dynamic Web Project

Tags: java, jar

I created a JPA project that I want to use in a dynamic web project.

I made a jar from this JPA project and added it in a lib folder in the dynamic webproject.  I then added this to the buildpath of the dynamic web project and also ticked it in the "Order and Export" tab.

First question : I created the jar file with a normal export to jar with these options;

[image]

Are these ok or do I have to add something.

Second question: After I added this jar to the buildpath and I use a instance of a class from within this  jar I can add it to the imports and the class is know so I don't see any errors.

When I try to run the jsp and servlet where I use the class I get a ***java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError*** error in my apache with a java.lang.ClassNotfoundEception at the line where I use the class.  So for some reason he doesn' find the class at runtime.

I tried to make the jar over and over again with different options.  I tried to import the class I need on different way's (ctrl-T) but I only see one class.

The only thing I find strange is the way the import looks.  In my JPA project I have a package structure like :

be.JPA.project6

in my dynamic web project I have a package structure like :

be.project6

when I see the import, I see : be.JPA.project6.data.classname

I would expect that a different structure so he would know that he needs to search outside the "normal" package structure.  But also with "ctrl-T" I only can see this class

I don't want to make a reference to the other project but use it like this with a jar.

I'm out of any clues at the moment, so any advise would be more then welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The build path is that: a build path. A path used to *build* the application.

The *runtime* classpath of a webapp is composed from the WEB-INF/class directory, and the set of jars in `WEB-INF/lib`.

Remove the jar from the build path of the dynamic web project. The just drop it into the `WebContent/WEB-INF/lib` directory. Eclipse will automatically add all the jars in this directory to the build path, and will put them in the `WEB-INF/lib` directory of the deployed web application, so that they're also part of the runtime classpath.